# discord.py Clean Content for emojis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How can I handle custom emojis and clean them? For example turn `<a:load:742504529278402560>` into just `:load:`?

There doesn't seem to be a built in way in the library to do this though.

Comment: if you have string `<a:load:742504529278402560>` then maybe use `split(':')` to get only `load` and then add `:` on both sides. OR use `regex` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```py
import re
def cleanemojis(string):
    return re.sub(r"<a?:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,32}):[0-9]{17,21}>", r":\1:", string)
```

```py
>>> cleanemojis("Loading <a:load:742504529278402560>")
"Loading :load:"
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably would want to use regex. Try this one:

```
import re

pattern = r":\w*:"

# NEXT IS JUST A TEST

string = "<a:load:742504529278402560>"
result = re.search(pattern, string)
print(result.group())
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way you could put it in a function and that it automatically cleans all the emoji names? Sorry I'm really bad at regex and don't know how to use it in Python currently.

Comment: I made your function and posting it as a separate answer, all credit goes to Arie Chertkov.

Answer (score 0):

As Arie Chertkov said, that would be the ideal way to do it. As per your request, I've written it into a function.

```
import re

pattern = r":\w*:"

def clean(string):
    result = re.search(pattern, string)
    return(result.group())

print(clean("<a:load:742504529278402560>"))
```

Comment: Ok but if you do something like `clean("hello there <a:load:742504529278402560>")` it just returns `:load:`. I want the emoji names to be cleared so the message returns `hello there :load:` or something